# Simple Function Matrix exercise; How do I do matrix arithmetic with non matrix numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Solve for $f(A)$ when:

$f(x) = 2 - 5x + x^2$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\4 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$ 
I can get \begin{bmatrix}-10 & 0\\-20 & -25\end{bmatrix} for $-5A$ and 
\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0\\28 & 25\end{bmatrix} for $A^2$
but after that I don't know what to do with \begin{bmatrix}-6 & 0\\8 & 0\end{bmatrix} because I also have to add $2$ to it? Do I just add $2$ to each entry? The answer is written in the book as \begin{bmatrix}-4 & 0\\8 & 2\end{bmatrix}

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

it is $f(A)=A^2-5A+2I_2$

Comment: So anytime I see a number not in matrix form, do I just assume to put it into an identity matrix? Thank you so much for helping me solve this trivial problem.

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: if it fits, it ships; I would appreciate if someone could tell me if that particular rule or trick has a name of some sort so I don't sound like a bumbling fool if I were ever to explain this sort of problem

Comment: @Charlatan If $V$ is a vector space over $k$ and $\bar{a}$ a basis of $V$, $f:V\to V$ a linear map and $q(x)\in k[x]$ then: if $A=(f:\bar{a})$ then $q(A)=(q(f):\bar{a})$